# unable to reset mysql 'root' password

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql 5.7.18. After installation the password of `root` user is `null`.
I have tried `mysql_secure_instattation` and following queries to reset ther password.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyPassword';
```

and

```
UPDATE mysql.user
    SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyPassword'), password_expired = 'N'
    WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

These methods executed successfully but still mysql root user is connecting `NULL` password.
What should I do ?

Comment: does it say `X rows affected`? or anything similar?

Comment: Did you restart the MySQL process?

Comment: Yes, It says `0 rows affected`

Comment: @VíctorLópez  Yes i restarted MySQL process

Comment: @Rajadip then that means the WHERE statement condition wasn't met - try adjusting the where - might be lower case field names that are messing you up :)

Comment: Using the `UPDATE mysql.user` query mentioned above , password gets updated, but still it taking `NULL` password while connecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to,MySQL is using `unix_socket` plugin instead of `mysql_native_password` plugin for root user which means mysql trusts the credentials of Linux root user. If you are loggied in with linux root user, MySQL won't ask for saperate credentials for MySQL root user. Hence even after changing password successfully for MySQL root user, it was connecting with No password.

Answer (score 0):

1. Forse stopping the server: if it is running as a service, use the task manager. (or with services)
2. Create a file C:\mysql-init.txt (for example) where you type:

> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';

3. Open the cmd (as administrator) and run this:

> ```
> C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin"
> C:\> mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
> ```

NOTE: if you are working with MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier, change the command line with this one:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your MySQL password with the following command too:

```
 mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass
```

Comment: Query didn't give any error but password doesn't get updated

Comment: I have the same MySQL version and it works for me. You should execute this on bash, not in MySQL.